# What is the meaning of time interval (timeIntervalSince1970) last three digit after decimal?

Tags: swift, date, timestamp

The timeIntervalSince1970 is showing a 10-digit value before the decimal and 6 digits after the decimal. Though the 3 digits (924) refer to the millisecond which is clear. But my concern is with the last 3 digits (567) what is its meaning?

```
(lldb) po Date().timeIntervalSince1970
1680153918.924567
```

Comment: 924567 microseconds.

Comment: Can you share any references?

Comment: It's basic units of math.

Comment: It is of type A TimeInterval value is always specified in seconds; it yields sub-millisecond precision over a range of 10,000 years.

Comment: I can guess it but I don't find any references like this

Comment: can you simplify your answer 'sub-millisecond precision over a range of 10,000 years', please? @WolfgangWilke

Comment: See Appledocs in the answer below for a reference

Comment: If a measure is in meters, do you wonder on the "1.123" value? Or is it clear enough that it corresponds to "1 m 12 cm 3 mm"?

Answer (score 2):

timeIntervalSince1970 is of type [TimeInterval](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate/1407504-timeintervalsince1970) and the is declared as:
A TimeInterval value is always specified in seconds; it yields sub-millisecond precision over a range of 10,000 years. [see Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timeinterval)